# Pandas/pyspark representative sample with occurences in different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, sample

I'm looking for creating a representative sample of specific dataframe.

My df is looks like:

```
query    | total
---------|-------
facebook | 123456
monkey   | 3456
iphone   | 54321
laptop   | 1234
headset  | 3333
plates   | 4333
girl     | 11222
.
.
.
```

I understood representative as:

1. every query can be displayed max once
2. every query has a probability of displaying by it's occurrence (in my case `total` column)

If I create a huge list (dataset with 1 col) with 123456 occurences of `facebook`, 3456 occurences of `monkey` etc and then do df.sample(something, something) it might work but I see it as super unefficient (considering having a huge dataset - literally millions, maybe billions of lines after putting into the "list" in my case)

Is here any other different (much more efficient) way of getting representative sample? Can be done in pandas or pyspark.

Example:

df with 8 queries and 20 occurences.

```
q1 | 1
q2 | 1
q3 | 5
q4 | 1
q5 | 2
q6 | 4
q7 | 4
q8 | 2
```

Let's say I need representative sample of 5 queries. Every query has a probability of being picked. q1 has 5%, q2 has 5%, q3 has 25% etc. Let's divide it into rolls. After the 1st roll - only one query is picked, for example q3. q3 is added into the final output and we roll again. 2. roll q5 is being picked and added into final output. 3. roll q3 is being picked AGAIN but it is not added into the final output bcs it is already there. Then we roll again and again after 5 spots of final output is being filled.

**Point is that a query with more occurences has higher chance being in the final output.**

Sadly I have much bigger datasets and it's not really possible for me to pick queries like this bcs the list of items (123456x facebook, 3456x monkey) would be way too big.

Comment: With `every query can be displayed only once`, do you mean that there should be only zero or one appearances of `facebook`, zero or one appearances of `monkey`, etc...?

Comment: Hello, yes. I tried to describe it in the example. Thanks ^^

Comment: May I ask why? It complicates things a lot and you cannot get a statistically correct sample of your data if you limit the number of appearances.

Comment: Well, it's a definition of representative sample (as I understood). You are looking for a sample which contains unique data but is affected by it's occurence. But it's not really what I'm looking for tho.. I'm looking for pyspark, pandas (maybe numpy?) func which takes data as they are in the first df I wrote and create a representative sample without making a HUUUGE list which might rip on memory.

Comment: Mmmmm, the way I understand it, a representative sample is not restricted to unique data. Take the following distribution `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]`. A representative sample of size 2 is very likely to be `[1,1]`, and a representative sample of size 4 could be `[1,1,1,2]`. The way you define it, your representative samples could never have a size bigger than the number of unique elements, which doesn't make sense if these elements themselves are repeated in the original distribution (which they are).

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that representative sampling can have multiple occurrences of values, you can compute the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) to generate intervals and `np.random` with `pd.cut` to draw normalized samples and assign them to the corresponding interval:

```py
import numpy as np

def draw_representative_samples(df, names_col='query', counts_col='total', n_samples=10):
    # Compute the Cumulative Density Function based on counts and normalize to [0,1]
    df_cdf = df[counts_col].cumsum() / df[counts_col].sum()
    
    # Draw Uniform samples in [0,1]
    samples = np.random.rand(n_samples)
    
    # Assign each sample to the corresponding interval using the CDF
    return pd.cut(
        x=pd.Series(samples),
        bins=pd.Series(0).append(df_cdf), # Add a 0 to the first interval
        labels=df[names_col].to_list(),   # label the samples using names_col
        precision=20)                     # Decimal positions to use for comparisons
```

We can try it out with an example:

```py
# Generating the dataframe from the example above
df = pd.DataFrame({'query':{0: 'facebook',  1: 'monkey',  2: 'iphone',  3: 'laptop', 
                            4: 'headset',  5: 'plates',  6: 'girl'},
                   'total':{0:123456, 1:3456, 2:54321, 3:1234, 4:3333, 5:4333, 6:11222}})

# getting our samples. Each run will give you different samples!
draw_representative_samples(df, n_samples=10).astype(str)

#> 0    facebook
#  1    facebook
#  2      iphone
#  3    facebook
#  4      iphone
#  5      iphone
#  6    facebook
#  7      monkey
#  8        girl
#  9      iphone
#  dtype: object
```